# Parallelization command possible bug

Tags: parallelization

In the following Mathematica compiled program, 3 persons take turns in a fair Russian Roulette Game with 1 bullet in the 6th chamber and we find the probabilities of each person being killed after 1,000,000 repetitions of the experiment,

The program:

```
  p = 3; n = 1000000.; arg = Table[0, n]; Roulette = 
  Compile[{i}, Module[{c = 1}, While[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
  != 6, c++]; m = Mod[c, p]; If[m != 0, m, p]], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; 
  Counts[Roulette[arg]]/n // AbsoluteTiming
```

with Parallelization -> True, gives nonsense whereas without:

```
  p = 3; n = 1000000.; arg = Table[0, n]; Roulette = 
  Compile[{i}, Module[{c = 1}, While[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
  != 6, c++]; m = Mod[c, p]; If[m != 0, m, p]], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},  
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; 
  Counts[Roulette[arg]]/n // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives correct answer.

By including local variable m in the module as in:

```
  p = 3; n = 1000000.; arg = Table[0, n]; Roulette = 
  Compile[{i}, Module[{m = 1,c = 1}, While[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
  != 6, c++]; m = Mod[c, p]; If[m != 0, m, p]], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; 
  Counts[Roulette[arg]]/n // AbsoluteTiming
```

we take the correct answer this time, but parallelization still fails.

Comment: The function is changing a global variable `m` and using it in the result, so that could be a problem.

Comment: I have tried initialization  {c = 1,m = 1} inside module, no avail. Also, do not forget to use first program with Parallelization -> True, not the second one.

Comment: In V12 on macOS, the first program gives me an error "Instruction 10 in CompiledFunction[...] calls ordinary code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time." Also, I get some probability that person 0 will be killed. Is that what you mean by it gives nonsense?

Comment: Yes, there is no 0 person by definition of: m = Mod[c, p]; If[m != 0, m, p]

Comment: I cannot get the bad behavior when I include `m` in the `Module` variable list. The bad case is less clear. The warning message claims to be foregoing parallelization but it appears all the same that the global `m` is getting reset asynchronously. Something is amiss but I am not sure what. Please post the code that localizes `m`, along with a run that shows the problematic result.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok, look at new edit of the original question now.

Comment: (1) I cannot get the bad behavior on my office Linux machine. Yet I saw it on my Windows laptop. Very strange. (2) Return `Mod[c,p,1]` from the `Module`-- it's faster that way.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielLichtblau, this gets rid of variable m altogether as well, still the program needs p to be declared inside the module to work in all kernels. I wouldn't call it a bug per se, I have written other versions of the same program which work with global variables, yet this particular one needs them all to be local.

Comment: It might work in parallelized form if `p` is a shared variable (though I'm not sure about the interaction between shared variables in parallelized code, and `Compile`). Or it could be a parameter passed to the compiled function. Or could do `Roulette=With[{p=p},Compile...]]` (I know, not very aesthetic).

Answer (score 1):

Program needs all variables p, c, m to be local inside the module:

```
n = 1000000.; arg = Table[0, n]; Roulette = 
Compile[{i}, Module[{p = 3,m = 1,c = 1}, While[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
!= 6, c++]; m = Mod[c, p]; If[m != 0, m, p]], 
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; 
Counts[Roulette[arg]]/n // AbsoluteTiming
```

There is no bug!